# error CS0012: The type 'ConnectionStringSettings' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced after upgrading to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, system.configuration

I've just upgraded from Visual Studio 2013 Pro to Visual Studio to 2015 (Enterprise), and when I compile my solution, I'm getting the following error:

> error CS0012: The type 'ConnectionStringSettings' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Is there anything I missed during the installation process? Do I have to manually add a reference to my projects from now on?

**UPDATE**: yes it does work after adding a reference to System.Configuration to the projects, but the question is more why do I need to do it in Visual Studio 2015 (it used to work without a reference in Visual Studio 2013)

**UPDATE**: To explain the context: I work in a team where developers work with various versions of Visual Studio (2012 onwards). If developers who work with Visual Studio < 2015 forget to manually add that reference, they won't get a compilation error, but the ones on VS2015 will. So it's important for the team to understand what's happening here :)

Comment: Have you done what the error message suggests (adding that assembly reference)?

Comment: Try add the reference to `System.Configuration`

Comment: My question is more: "how come I need to do it with VS2015 but not in VS2013"

Comment: Explain the downvote? I still don't have an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two reasons why you suddenly have to add an explicit reference to `System.Configuration.dll` in VS 2015 when you did not have to do this in earlier versions of VS:

- During the solution migration / update, your projects' .NET Framework settings were changed to a newer .NET Framework. In the newer .NET Framework version, the `ConnectionStringSettings` type was moved to a different assembly.

  To be honest, this seems unlikely to me, but could be checked.
- The build system's (MSBuild) `.targets` have changed in VS 2015. The previous build targets automatically added references to the `System.Configuration.dll` assembly, whereas the newer build targets don't do that anymore; which is why you now have to add the missing assembly references manually.

  (Note how when you create a project in Visual Studio, the build system usually takes care of references to `mscorlib`, `System`, and `System.Core`. Even if you remove these assembly references, they are still "there" during compilation. Perhaps something similar has been going on for `System.Configuration` prior to VS 2015.)

  I haven't verified this, but it seems the likelier explanation of the two.

These are just attempts at explaining this (aka guesses), so perhaps there is an altogether different reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. VS2015 installed the .Net 4.6 framework, but we are still targeting .Net 4.5 in the project (no change), so I do not believe in the first explanation either.